# Cannot find sqlserver service

Tags: sql-server, ssms, windows, sql-server-2019

I installed Sql Server 2019 in Windows PC.

In Sql Server Configuration Manager into SQL Server Service I stopped all the instances.

But still I can loggin to Sql Server via SSMS.why is that? Where is the Sql Server service?

In Windows Services I can see SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER01) that running and when I stopped it,I can't login to sqlserver. But why I can't see that service running in Sql Server Configuration Manager into SQL Server Service.

I login with server name:DESKTOP-IJ7544\MSSQLSERVER01

Comment: If you open your **Windows Services** and sort alphabetically, do you see any **SQL Server** services still running?

Comment: In **Windows Services** I can see SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER01) that running and when I stopped  it,I can't login to sqlserver. But why I can't see that service running in Sql Server Configuration Manager into SQL Server Service ??

Comment: You start MMC.EXE then "Add/Remove SnapIn" you should see multiple SQL Server Configuration manager entries.  I think it's one for each major version you have installed.  And they can't all see all the instances (I have no idea why).

Comment: So how can I enable TCP/IP for service that not in Server Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of SQL Server installed on a PC:

1. Server based - named instances such as \sqlexpress, \instance name or unnamed instances such as . All of these instances can be stopped by going to services.msc and stopping the service. By default, most people install unnamed instances on PCs unless they fully intend to install a named instance.
2. File-based - this is your localDB that may come with an installation of Visual Studio

From all indications, you may have more than one server-based installation - a unnamed instance for which you have stopped the service in services.msc and a named instance which you can still connect to.

I would go to services.msc and check to see if any of the sql instances services have a status of running. If they do, that’s why. While in services, typing “s” or “sq” fast enough should get you there faster.

Sql configuration is great for particular versions but may not reveal other instances beyond the version for which it was installed.

Comment: See my update.How can Ienable TCP/IP for service that not in Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: 2 ways. Run select @@version to figure out what version of sql server you have in your instance that isn’t showing up in your sql config. Then see if you can install the correct version of sql config. Another old trick is to change the protocol for a particular instance for the whole server is to create a system ODBC connection to the instance and change the connection protocol to your preference. Even if the odbc is never used, it changes the default connection protocol for the whole pc/server to use that protocol for any connections.

Comment: In what way is LocalDB file-based? It's still a server, it just has a special startup sequence, and doesn't appear in configuration manager, as it can only be accessed from localhost

Comment: It is file-based in that access is based solely-based on file system access vs the server versions which have a service which manage defined permissions. Local DB files share the same characteristics as an msaccess file or MSSQL instance set to exclusive use - once I open it, no one else can. Yes it runs on demand and allows the creation of instances (which be done on the command line with sqllocaldb.exe) but it is not a server application

Comment: Good read in the permission section at the end here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15